# Silverlight and MVC Sample Project

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-mvc-2

I am currently planning to develop a sample websites to learn and demonstrate Silverlight(MVVM) and ASP.NET MVC framwork. I am thinking of working on sample E-Commerce (anyother ideas welcome!) site.

I am planning to keep the database structure and the WCF services which interact with the data the same so that I can have seperate front end using silverlight and ASP.NET MVC architecture.

Is there any good end to end project that is available which can point me towards a correct direction?

Any other recommendations it can be anything from architecture to coding principles.

I sincerely appreciate your time and support.

Comment: You are asking too many things. Try to narrow down and focus on the different topics independently.

Comment: Why did you pick these? Are you experienced in these technologies?

Comment: Yes. I have worked on WCF services extensively. I have done some ASP.NET MVC2 and some WPF and silverlight.

Comment: Darin, Sorry if it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

For the MVC part you should take a look at : http://mvcstarter.codeplex.com/